# Would you wrap PDO or extend it?

Tags: php, pdo

<del>[My question is fairly clear,](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/2314802#2314802) and</del> I really would like to hear some reasons for the answer.

Additional information:

- I don't use any kind of PHP Framework.
- PHP > 5.3.

**Update:**

Right now I don't have much of restrictions around my project, it's a one man project *yet* and I have worked hard to make everything as lose coupled and modular as possible. same as I was told, I didn't liked the PDO API after playing with it for a while, but that is no big issue if sticking to it's Public API will give me any more flexibility or is considered good practice.

So my question is, What would you gain and lose by using Composition or Inheritances considering the object in question is an Abstraction layer itself, PDO in this case, ?

> tl;dr: One man project trying to be Modular as possible, Composition
> or Inheritance for using a *3rd party* abstraction layer (PDO
> specifically) ?

<sub>Note: if it's not the right place, Vote to migrate to Programmers. and sorry for my bad english.</sub>

Comment: @Downvoter: Care to elaborate ?

Comment: This invites quite a discussion (which is why you're seeing down votes, and we're seeing flags). If you could revise this to include your end game in this scenario .. the answers could be much more objective and this would probably be on topic at Programmers SE. Remember, Stack Overflow is for _real problems that you face_, so a more concrete scenario is needed either way (if theoretical, then Programmers would be the better place).

Comment: @TimPost Thanks for clearing things up, Updated my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm a fan of wrapping for "3rd party" classes as that way you're much less dependent on the support for the class. If someone would later on change function names on PDO your code would change around all your code. With wrapping only the wrapping class would change as your interface is independent.

Answer (score 3):

I generally would not bother wrapping it unless you do not like the API. If you do decide to go down this route then I would use [Idiorm](http://j4mie.github.com/idiormandparis/) (and possible [Paris](http://j4mie.github.com/idiormandparis/) for active record) rather than rolling my own.

I would never think of extending a third party extension unless I planned to maintain its code as well or never upgrade that library. By wrapping your are sandboxing the third party library away from your code as much as possible so that you will be less affected by changes to their code.